# Every time I move my handle bar left or right the wheel turns in different direction

Tags: bmx

I crashed my bike and now every time I push on the front wheel a little, or if I turn the handle bar a little hard the wheel turns in the other direction.

What could cause this and what can I do about it?

Comment: I recommend taking the bike to a bike shop. It seems that something is broken. Perhaps with more information, explanation, and photos, we could help, but a shop should be able to diagnose it quickly.

Comment: Meanwhile, it sounds like the bike is not safe to ride.

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like the handlebar stem is loose. **This is an extremely dangerous situation** and you should go immediately (pushing your bike or taking it in a car, but **not riding it**) to your local bike shop to have it looked at.

The fix is easy and should take less than 5 minutes (and only a few dollars/euro if they charge you at all), but again it is critical that you get this repaired.